# SharePoint Modern experience - ClientSidePage Section Background - How to Color?

Tags: background-color, sharepoint-online, client-side-templating

i have an tricky issue. I have to find a solution to color (Background) a 
ClientSidePage "Section". I created an template with SharePoint Online PnP.

If I export a Template XML file with the command "Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate", there are no values for the Background Color of the sections.

To add ClientSidePageSection there is a Command "Add-PnPClientSidePageSection", but no possibility to color the Background, there is no way to give a value for the color.

Is there a way to color the section? Or is there a way to copy 
an .aspx site with colored sections? If I copy that manually, the sections are colored. Maybe there's a way to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this helps, but I did notice in the changelog (https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), the following:

[3.5.1901.0]

Added

- Added Reset-PnPFileVersion cmdlet

Changed

- Add-PnPClientSidePageSection: Added support for section the section background of a client side page

Implying that the section background maybe exported. If you are not running that version, maybe try updating and see if that works.